# SP13 Calendar Workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow, designer-workflow, sharepoint-calendar

I am new to workflows but getting better daily.  I am trying to create a workflow for a calendar.  I would like for the workflow to operate as follows... when user enters a entry into "Calendar A" I would like the user to select in a drop down box another calendar they would like for the entry to appear in too.  See example below.

[image]

I need assistance getting started with this workflow.  Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF I understand the requirement correctly, you need to:

1. Add a list which contains the names and IDs of all the calendars (Calendar 1, 2, 3).
2. Add a field with a lookup to this list in Calendar A. Display the title but the value must be the ID of that particular calendar. Be sure this field is in the newitem form.
3. Add a workflow in Calendar A on creation of a new item.
4. You can use the activities under the "List" group in the toolbox to achieve everything you need: You will first need to get the ID of the calendar you are going to copy the item to (marked in blue in your diagram). You can do this by using LookupSPListItem > and in the properties you will need to specify the field in #2.
5. Once you have acquired the ID, you can use the a) GetCurrentItemID and b) CopyItem activity to copy from the source list to the destination list ID (acquired in #4).
6. You can then delete the item from Calendar A once it has been successfully copied.

Comment: @SharePointLady I'm glad to see new people getting into sp2013 workflows. I think right now you can count the active people here using them on one hand!